# subclasses and hql

Tags: java, hibernate, polymorphism, hql

I have a class and subclasses who extends that.
Like this:

```
    @Table
    @Entity
    class Cat{



    class DomesticCat extends Cat{
       LitterBox litterBox;

    //getter and setters


    }

    class TigerCat extends Cat{
       HuntingStyle huntingStyle;

    //getter and setters
    }


}
```

I want to query with hql.

For example i want to find the cat who has "blue" colored LitterBox

should i add @entity and @Table annotations before DomesticCat and TigerCat classes?

There is no column in database for subclass specific fields like litterBox and huntingStyle.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Entity needs to be added for `DomesticCat` and `TigerCat` if you want to persist them. You can use the @Inheritance annotation for defining how the subclasses should be mapped - for a single table, use `@Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE)`.

@Table will be defaulted if you don't add it.

Comment: thanks very much for answer. where should i write @Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE) to parent class or every subclasses. and do i understand right, if i write this all the classes can be mapped to a single table, right?

Comment: You should add the @Inheritance(strategy=SINGLE_TABLE) to the parent class. All of it's subclasses will then be mapped to the parent class's table.